# Mouseover Function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

Lets try something more simple.  I have a pink box and I want it to turn from pink to red when the user mouseovers it.  This function is not working.  Can anyone help me fix the code or find the error??  They have told me if I can't get this working I am going to be let go!!

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<style type="text/css"> 
#input
{
margin-top:-200px;

}
</style>

</head>

<body style="background-color:black";>



<div id="draw-here-raphael" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background: #666; z-index:0;">
</div>

<div id="input" style="z-index:99;" >
  <input type="text" value="0"; style="text-align:right;" /><br />
</form> 
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//all your javascript goes here
$(function() {
var r = new Raphael("draw-here-raphael"),

    // Store where the box is
    position = 'left',

    // Make our pink rectangle
    rect = r.rect(20, 20, 250, 300, 10).attr({"fill": "#fbb"});
    $("rect").(function(i) {
        $("rect").mouseover(function() {
            $("rect").attr({"fill": "red"});
        });
    }); 
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `attr()` (as with most of jQuery) doesn't work with SVG -- the elements produced by raphael. Do you need the rectangle to be SVG? If it was a Div it'd be no problem.

Comment: I need the rectangle to turn red when the user mouses over it...so yes..i think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `$("rect")` to just `rect`

```
rect = r.rect(20, 20, 250, 300, 10).attr({"fill": "#fbb"});
rect.(function(i) {
    rect.mouseover(function() {
        rect.attr({"fill": "red"});
    });
});
```

However as someone pointed out in a comment it may not work with SVG.

If you have the rect as a div with height and width, fixed position with left and top and a background-color you can just change the css value of background-color on mouseover.

For a div example:

Suppose you have a div with `id="pinkBox"`

```
$('#pinkBox').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
});
```

You will need to position the div too, I'm not sure how the Raphael stuff works, never looked at it personally, but if its fixed positioning then you can emulate this in css with `position:fixed; top: some value; left: some value; width: some value; height: some value`

Full code:

HTML:

```
<div id="pinkBox" style="position:fixed; left:20, top:20; width:250; height:300" ></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pinkBox').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
    });
});
```

Unfortunately if you are not using CSS3 you will not be able to have rounded corners unless you use images.  Using CSS3 though you can add rounded corners by adding the following style to the div

```
border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
```

For simplicity I have added the styles inline on the div, I would suggest making a class though and using the class attribute, keeping your css in a seperate file or in the head of your document.

Comment: Did you read my edit?  I did mention that as @bokonic had mentioned it may not work with SVG.  I will reedit to include a div example

Comment: could you post the entire code with your edit.  I am trying to incorporate it, but it is still not working..

Comment: thank you! please +1 my question and I will approve your answer as soon as I can.  You were very helpful!!!

Answer (score 1):

why dnt u use css for this

```
#draw-here-raphael:hover{background-color:Red;}
```

Or, Use this code instead

```
$(rect).mouseover(function() {
    this.attr({"background-color": "red"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it around a bit, but what about something like this:

```
var canvas = Raphael(document.getElementById("draw-here-raphael"));

// Make rectangle pink
var r = canvas.rect(20, 20, 250, 300, 10).attr("fill", "#fbb");

$("#draw-here-raphael").mouseover(function() {
    r.attr("fill", "red");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7PLy9/

Comment: I actually figured it out.  I came up with something very similar to that.  Thanks for your help.  PLease +1 my question and I will +1 your answer. :)